# Auto Stock Update after Order cancel from Admin of Woocommerce?

Tags: plugins, order

I recently implemented Woocommerce and in trial session I found following issue:

**1.**
Initially, I provide 10qty for Product1.
**2.** 
place a Dummy Order from front-end of 10qty of that Product1.
**3.** 
Then After that I see Product1 is Out of Stock.
**4.** 
From Admin of woocommerce, If I cancelled that dummy order or reduce the product qty on that order, It Doesn't Update the Stock Qty of that product1.

And I still see the Out of stock label on that product even after that order has been cancelled which reserved this qty.

Hence is their any way to Auto-Manage this Stock Updates between orders and Inventory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry to Trouble this Slept world of Wordpress.
I got My answers From Awaked wordpress world,directly from Author of Plugin here:
http://ilikekillnerds.com/2012/07/the-problem-with-woocommerce-its-crap/